# how do I check student_id before input student class record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My thought of this programming content as below:  'adult' symbolize the student data table and 'adultclasses' symbolize course selection data table.

When the data keyin person input the student data,they have to avoid input the student_id which not existing in adult content. However, I’ve  try several times still fail.

```
def create
    @adult_class = AdultClasse.new(params[:adult_classe])
    @adults_session_descriptions = AdultsSessionDescription.all
    if 
      @adult_class = @adult_class.find(:student_id) == Adult.find_by_student_id(:student_id)       
      flash[:notice] = "no this student id record!"
      redirect_to:action => :index       
    else   
         respond_to do |format|
        if @adult_class.save
          format.html { redirect_to(@adult_class, :notice => 'adult classe was successfully created.') }
          format.xml  { render :xml => @adult_class, :status => :created, :location => @adult_class }
        else
          format.html { render :action => "new" }
          format.xml  { render :xml => @adult_class.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end
```

Because I was mistaken use plural names to build the program, I’ve made up in adultclasse.rb as below:

```
# encoding: utf-8
class AdultClasse < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "adult_classes"
  belongs_to :adult
  #has_many :adults_classe_ship 
  #has_many :adult, :through => :adults_classe_ship 
  validates :student_id,  :presence =>  {:message => "please input student id"}, 
                          :length => {:message => "too short or too long", :minimum => 4, :maximum => 12}        
end
```

this is model Adult.rb

```
# encoding: utf-8
    class Aadult < ActiveRecord::Base  
    before_save :fix_cname

  def age
    now = Time.now.utc.to_date
    dob = self.birthday
    now.year - dob.year - ((now.month > dob.month || (now.month == dob.month && now.day >= dob.day)) ? 0 : 1)
  end

  private
  def fix_cname
   self.cname = self.cname.gsub(/[\w\s\b\$[:punct:]]/ , '')
  end      

  #has_many :adults_classe_ship, :dependent => :destroy
  #has_many :adult_classe, :through => :adults_classe_ship
```

Comment: What is `adults_classe_ship`?  Please also post the `Adult` class.

Comment: If Adult does not have an ability to input student_id, why do you make it possible in form? you can also delete it from ```params[:adult_classe]```. Just do ```params[:adult_classe].delete(:student_id)```

Comment: You need to clarify sth for me: what is an exact relationship between AdultClasse and Adult? You are validating student_id field, but I don't see any `:student` relationship or any relatioship pointing to this field.

Comment: hi  BroiStase this is mine adult_classe_ship.rb

`code`
    class AdultsClasseShip < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :adult
      belongs_to :adult_classe
   end
`code`
but this is wrong settings I will delete ti soon